# How to print unsigned 64 bit integer

Tags: ocaml

I'm tackling this [smallest multiple problem](https://open.kattis.com/problems/smallestmultiple) on Kattis.

I've solved it in Python and C++, but now I want to do OCaml.

Here's my code:

```
open Printf;;

let rec gcd (a : int64) (b : int64) : int64 =
    if not (Int64.unsigned_compare b 0L > 0) then
        a
    else
        gcd b (Int64.unsigned_rem a b);;

try
    while true;
    do
        let line = read_line ()
        in
        if String.length line > 0 then
            let (nums : int64 list) = List.map (fun (s:string) : (int64) ->
                (Int64.of_string (Char.escaped '0' ^ Char.escaped 'u' ^ s ))) (String.split_on_char ' ' line)
            in
            let rec reduce (li : int64 list) (init : int64) : (int64) =
                match li with
                | [] -> init
                | head :: tail -> reduce tail ( Int64.unsigned_div (Int64.mul head init) (gcd head init) ) 
            in
            print_string ( Int64.to_string (reduce nums 1L) ^ "\n")
        else
            raise End_of_file
    done;
with End_of_file -> ();;
```

I can get the first case to pass, but the second (and final) case results in a wrong answer. This is weird since my logic is the same in my two earlier submissions of different languages.

My guess is that I'm incorrectly printing unsigned 64 bit integers:

```
print_string ( Int64.to_string (reduce nums 1L) ^ "\n")
```

Earlier, I've tried:

```
printf "%Lu\n" (reduce nums 1L)
```

But the [Printf documentation](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Printf.html) says

```
u, n, l, L, or N: convert an integer argument to unsigned decimal. Warning: n, l, L, and N are used for scanf, and should not be used for printf.
```

and I actually don't think this warning is relevant in my case, but I'm still wary.

Any thoughts? Thanks for reading!

Comment: It would help if you gave an example input that fails. All of the examples on the page you link to are working for me. I.e., the output is the same as on the linked page.

Comment: Your code works fine and I don't see any reason why it shouldn't. Concerning, printf you should use the `%Lu` modifier.

Comment: Bad news: My code still doesn't pass Kattis' test cases with or with the `printf` statement. Also, in hopes to keep us thinking, Kattis will not share its test cases.

Good news: I ran `123412341234 14441441 355548333 55858858 345252345245` as example random input in my OCaml program and got back `466941151233371166`. I did this same input for my successful C++ program and got back `1`. So we are indeed getting wrong output somehow.

Comment: It may be because of a lack of an easily available 'Big Integer' library within OCaml.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me. You might consider restarting OCaml from scratch, then copy/pasting the above code. That's what I did, and it worked for me.

```
. . .
  with End_of_file -> ();;
2 3 5
30
1 2 3 4
12
399 772 163 959 242
832307365428

- : unit = ()
#
```

I have a 64-bit system, for what it's worth. I.e., max_int is 4611686018427387903 for me.

Comment: Just to make it clear, max_int shall not be relative for that program as it is using int64 that is always 64 bit.

Comment: Sure, just thinking of possible system differences.

Answer (score 0):

466941151233371166 isn't a multiple of any of the inputs so that is clearly wrong. The input numbers are rather large so my guess is you simply have an integer overflow. On the other hand your C++ code says 1, which also isn't a multiple of any of the numebrs and also clearly wrong.

I can see one spot that is likely the problem:

```
( Int64.unsigned_div (Int64.mul head init) (gcd head init) )
```

As you process the input the `init` gets larger and larger and you multiply it by the next number. Only after you divide it by th GCD. It temporarily exceeds 64bit in that step and you loose bits.

By the definition of the GCD both head and init are divisible by it. So why not divide one of them by the GCD before the multiplication:

```
(Int64.mul init (Int64.unsigned_div head (gcd head init)))
```

That way you never have an intermediate number larger than the result and results that come close to the 64bit limit still produce the right result.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! I saw they're were giving different output and immediately assumed OCaml's was wrong. Unfortunately, the second test case still didn't pass when multiplying after division.

Comment: Because the smallest multiple for `123412341234 14441441 355548333 55858858 345252345245` is `41567042729633820981190887227101634992940430` which requires 145 bit. It can't be solved with just 64bit.

Comment: What happened to the [Big_int module](https://ocaml.org/releases/4.05/htmlman/libref/Big_int.html)? How do I get it for OCaml version 4.10.0 ?